# How can I call columns with column names in Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, multiple-columns

I have hundreds of csv files. Each one need not necessarily have the same headers like below.

```
CSV1:
G,B,C,D
1,2,3,4
2,4,5,6

CSV2:
A,C,D
1,2,6
2,5,7
```

I'd like to call each column by its name, like this:
if file has column A: select that column
else: skip to the next required column (which could be B) and repeat the same process for each file until all the required columns have been referenced. I'd really really appreciate if you could help me do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call following function with the desired column name and it returns list of all values belonged to this column:

```
import csv

file = 'c:\\temp\\test.csv'

def GetValuesFromColumn(title):

  values = []
  rownum = 0
  with open(file, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
      if rownum == 0:
        index = row.index(title)
        rownum = 1
      else:
        values.append(row[index])

  return values

values = GetValuesFromColumn('D')
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: use the `csv` module's `DictReader`.

Solution 2: if you data is really numerical, as in your example, you could use `numpy.genfromtxt` to  produced structured arrays: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html

Answer (score 0):

if you'd like a Pandas approach, here's an option. It opens each file, grabs one row, looks at the columns and sees if any of the column names are in the desired list. If there are any columns we want it reads the csv into a Pandas DataFrame

example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( [(2014, 30, 15), (2015, 10, 20), (2007, 5, 3)] )
df.columns = ['year','a','b']
df.set_index('year', inplace=True)
df.to_csv('tst.csv')
df.columns  = ['c','z']
df.to_csv('tst2.csv')
```

Do the work:

import glob

```
wanted = ['year','a','z']
path = '.'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
for file in allFiles:
    #grab only one row for testing
    df = pd.read_csv(file, nrows=1)
    includedCols = []
    for x in wanted:
        if x in df.columns:
            includedCols.append(x) 
    if len(includedCols) > 0:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols = includedCols)
        print df
        ## do something with df here
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`csv.DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

> Create an object which operates like a regular reader but maps the information read into a dict whose keys are given by the optional fieldnames parameter.
>
> If the fieldnames parameter is omitted, the values in the first row of the csvfile will be used as the fieldnames.

For example

```
import csv
def get_values_for_column(csvfile, col):
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        values = [row[col] for row in reader]
        return values

# Usage
>> get_values_for_column('CSV1.csv', 'D')
# prints [4, 6]
```

*Based on the answers from both Alan and Aldervan*